# Change DIV background color for all inputs in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keyup

I have a form with 20 input fields. Each input field is inside a DIV. I have a script that changes the background color of the DIV via keyup function along with two other DIV tags.

Rather than duplicating the script 20 times for each DIV and Input, is it possible to re-write the script to do all DIV's and their Inputs?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").keyup(function() {
       if($("#id").val().length > 0) $("#in1, #nu1, #lw1, #id").css("background-color","#2F2F2F").css("color", "#FFF");
       else {
 if($("#id").val().length == 0) $("#in1, #nu1, #lw1, #id").css("background-color","#E8E8E8").css("color", "#000");
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are correct if you want all of the divs to change color at once, but I don't know that is what you are asking for.

My assumption is that you have multiple pieces of code like this:

```
<div>
   <input>
</div>
```

And when the input is longer than 0, you want the container div to change colors.  If so, this is what you can do:

First, Give the divs a common class, such as `input-div`:

```
<div class="input-div">
   <input>
</div>
```

Create css classes:

```
.input-div {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #E8E8E8
}
.highlight {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #2F2F2F
}
```

Then, use on jQuery call to apply/remove the highlight class for each case:

```
$(".input-div input").keyup(function() {
   // Get parent div
   var myParent = $(this).parent('.input-div');

   // If input length is > 0, highlight the parent
   if($(this).val().length > 0) {
       myParent.addClass('highlight');
   } else {
       myParent.removeClass('highlight');
   }
});
```

You don't need the extra `if`, because if length is not `> 0`, it will be `== 0`.  If you want other divs to change color as well, you would need to give them a class/id, or know their location relative to the `input-div`.  I can't help you there without seeing your html.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QB52B/

Comment: Use `toggleClass()` instead and your code becomes way simpler!

Comment: @JamundFerguson: Generally that is true.  In this case, I left it as an `if`/`then`, because he may want additional code for the other "other" divs he mentions.  If they can all be toggled as well, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the inputs and replace #id with .classname. Something along these lines:

```
$(".classname").keyup(function() {
if($(this).val().length > 0) $(this).parent().css("background-color",
 "#2F2F2F").css("color", "#FFF");
 else {
 if($(".classname").val().length == 0) $(this).parent().css("background-color",
 "#E8E8E8").css("color", "#000");
}

});
```

Comment: no if your input is in the div you should able to target the inputs parent which will be the div. if you want to target more than one div give the divs a class and target that class.

Answer (score 0):

### Normal jQuery Approach

Here are my suggestions for a normal jQuery approach. We can clean up the code a whole bunch using these basic ideas.

1. Use @Adil's solution to add a class to reference all of your inputs at once or even just `$("input[type=text]")` or whatever.
2. Use a `.toggleClass()` to handle the styling!

Example JS:

```
var $inputs = $("input[type=text]"); // or replace with className
$inputs.keyup(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.toggleClass("isEmpty", $this.val().length > 0)
});
```

Example CSS:

```
input[type=text] { /* or replace with className */
  color: black;
  background: gray;
}

.isEmpty {
   color: gray;
   background: black;
}
```

This keeps your styling in your stylesheet where they belong. `toggleClass` also keeps your code cleaner.

### Pure CSS Approach

If you ever get to drop older browsers and want to use pure CSS styling it shouldn't be much a stretch as it seems you're doing something like this. Check out this [article on css-tricks about styling placeholder text](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: gray;
   background: black;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
   color: gray;
   background: black;
}
```